# Strange Pointer Behavior

Tags: c++

Take the following struct and class:

```
struct TestStruct
{
};

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestStruct* testStruct;
};
```

Do the following in `main`:

```
TestClass testClass;
if (testClass.testStruct == NULL)
    cout << "It is NULL." << endl;
else
    cout << "It is NOT NULL.";
```

The output will be: `It is NOT NULL.`.

However, if I instead do this:

```
TestClass testClass;
if (testClass.testStruct == NULL)
    cout << "It is NULL." << endl;
else
    cout << "It is NOT NULL." << endl << testClass.testStruct;
```

The output will be: `It is NULL.`.

Interestingly enough, if I do this (fundamentally the same as above):

```
TestClass testClass;
if (testClass.testStruct == NULL)
{
    cout << "It is NULL." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "It is NOT NULL." << endl;
    cout << testClass.testStruct;
}
```

The output will be:

```
It is NOT NULL.
0x7fffee043580.
```

What is going on?

Comment: exmaple of Undefined behaviour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your pointer is not initialized when you declare `testClass`. You experience here an undefined behaviour. The value of the pointer will be the last value that was contain in the memory section where it is stored.

If you wanted it to **always** be `NULL`, you would need to initialize it in the constructor of your class.

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(): testStruct(NULL) {}
    TestStruct* testStruct;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

### ***Answer***

For me it displays **"It is NOT NULL"** in both questions and **sometimes you may get it as NULL**

The reason for above scenario to occur is that C++ doesn't automatically assign anything to a variable, Therefore it contains an unknown value

so that unknown value may be NULL sometimes but sometimes it may be not

the best way to test this theory is to try it in visual C++ and g++ and any other c++ compiler

Yet another reason for you to get either null or not null is that **when you compile the application in different ways the compiler outputs different executables** so in one undefined variable scenario the **compiler may output an executable which when executed may point the undefined variable to a NULL or NOT NULL**

### ***A Test using GNU C++ compiler and Microsoft Command line compiler***

**warning don't use this code IT'S BAD (this is a test for undefined variable scenario in two compilers)**

code (based on OP) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct TestStruct
{
};

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestStruct* testStruct;


};

int main(){
    TestClass testClass;
    if (testClass.testStruct == NULL)
        cout << "It is NULL." << endl;
    else
        cout << "It is NOT NULL." << endl << testClass.testStruct;
}
```

GNU G++
[image: GNU G++ test]

Visual Studio CL

[image: CL]

Comment: "that should be the one that you should get most of the time" is both wrong and misleading.  This is undefined behavior, so it will be undefined.  Using uninitialized variables will give unpredictable results because it is undefined.

Comment: @ZacHowland : thanks sir I've modified my answer please consider removing the down vote

I agree with what you said

Answer (score 3):

The `testStruct` will sometimes be NULL and sometimes not be NULL.

Make sure your constructor clears the pointer.  Variables in C++ are not default to NULL/0.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Pointer doesn't get initialized by default. You'll have to do that in the constructor. It just contains what's in your RAM. On usual 32 bit systems the propability of it being NULL is around 0,2e-9. on 64 bit systems ( in 64 bit assemblies) it will be even lower.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you didn't initialized the `testStruct` member. You have an *Undefined behaviour* here. It contains garbage value.

If you want it to be always initialized to `NULL`, you can do :

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(): testStruct(NULL) {}
    TestStruct* testStruct;
};
```

Or with the **c++11** way :

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestStruct* testStruct{NULL}; // or TestStruct* testStruct = NULL;
};
```

All the three examples in live : http://ideone.com/ge25Zr

---

As it is said in the comment, to complete with the C++11 way, you could use `nullptr` :

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestStruct* testStruct = nullptr; // or TestStruct* testStruct{nullptr};
};
```

---

By the way, it is a better practice to keep member attributes private or at least protected. You should create accessors to retreive them.

Comment: In c++11 you'd use nullptr, not NULL (Edit: And in fact you'd also just use testStrcut = nullptr; too!

Comment: @paulm You are right, I added that to my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.